# How to read .xpt files?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a R shiny app that reads xpt files.

The code below reads a csv file and displays a table; however, I am searching for a way to view/display the same from .xpt file using the function `sasxport.get.` Could someone help me how to do this in R shiny?

**app.R**(currently it reads csv)

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `read_xpt` from haven package.  Try this

```
library(haven)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # output$contents <- renderTable({
  #   # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
  #   # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
  #   # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
  #   # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
  #   # be found.
  #   inFile <- input$file1
  #   
  #   if (is.null(inFile))
  #     return(NULL)
  #   
  #   read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  # })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read_xpt(inFile$datapath) 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```